# Jenkins not failing build with Unity Fail

Tags: jenkins

I have just set up a Jenkins server. This integrated with my github repo, and Jenkins is pulling the repo as expected.
My build makefile runs some Unity tests which which works fine. But Jenkins is marking the build as a success, even if I force them Unity tests to fail.
Do I need to configure unity to check for the "Fail" in the Unity console output?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can consider using the [Log parser plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/) to parse the console logs and fail based on particular log patterns